# Rotation of Radar Axis in 3D plane

Tags: sensors, mathematics, radar, kalman-filters

I'm working on a sensor fusion application.
In our vehicle, 4 radars (fixed, non-rotating radars) are placed at 4 corners of the vehicles at 45 degrees with respect to x, y and z-axes of the vehicle.
For proper working of the sensor-fusion algorithm we need to offset all detected objects to the center of the vehicle.

The Radar axis are oriented as below

[image]

Radars are installed on vehicle as below:

[image]

Currently I was planning to use below formula to cater 2D rotations:
x ́=x cos⁡θ+y sin⁡θ
y ́=y cos⁡θ-x sin⁡θ
Where ((x) ́,y ́) are the new coordinates of the same point but when its Radar axis is rotated by an angle θ.

However since z-axis of the radar is not parallel to the z-axis of vehicle I'm unable to use the above formula.
Kindly advice on how can I rotate the z-axis of radar to make it parallel to vehicular z-axis.

Comment: If you are not able to rotate the radar axes to vehicle axes with a single rotation about `Z` axis, then you need two (or three) successive rotations. However, I am not able to visualise the axes from the diagram given in the question. Do you have a *proper* top view, front view and side view of the setup rather than the *3D-ish* view given currently in the question ?

Comment: Not sure what you need to obtain. However, formulation and handling will be easier when you start using vectors (for positions, orientations, speed etc.) and matrices (at least for rotations; you can determine them from misaligned radar-vectors for example). Examples. Shift: $\vec r_{new}=\vec r_{radar}+\vec r_{offset3}$; Rotation: $\vec n_{radar4} = M_4 \times \vec {Orientation}_{radar4}$, where M is a matrix. // Once you have this set of vector equations, dealing with components become "easier", i.e. less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

In the Cartesian system were each vector is an compound number, should be able to do a dot product with the vehicles Z axis to get the required projection or any axis for that matter.